# Choosing random function

Tags: python-3.x

I wan't my python program to select a random function. 
I have this code:
I get error: NameError: name 'good' is not defined

What am i doing wrong, please help.

```
    import random

class functions:
    def jammer():
        print("jammer")

    def goedzo():
        print("goedzo")

    def uuh():
        print("uuh")

    def tsjing():
      print("tsjing")

 #random functonlist
    ls_good = [goedzo, tsjing]
    ls_wrong = [jammer, uuh]

    #method to select different functions
    #def __init__(self, g = random.choice(ls_good), f = random.choice(ls_wrong)):
    def randomfunction(self, good = random.choice(ls_good), wrong = random.choice(ls_wrong)):
        self.good = good
        self.wrong = wrong
        return self.good
        return self.wrong

#create object from class playsound
selected_function = functions()
selected_function.randomfunction(good, wrong)
```

Comment: Note that `randomfunction` only initializes its default arguments ONCE: when the function is **defined**. If you need them to be random every time you call it, then the `random.choice` needs to move inside your function, so that it runs every time the function is **called**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thnx for youre answers!
I managed to get what i wan't by doing this:

```
    import random

class functions:
    def jammer():
        print("jammer")

    def goedzo():
        print("goedzo")

    def uuh():
        print("uuh")

    def tsjing():
      print("tsjing")

 #random functonlist
    ls_good = [goedzo, tsjing]
    ls_wrong = [jammer, uuh]

    #method to select different functions
    def randomfunction(self, test, good = random.choice(ls_good), wrong = random.choice(ls_wrong)):
        self.good = good
        self.wrong = wrong
        self.test = test
        if self.test == 1:
            good()
        else:
            wrong()
#create object from class playsound
sf = functions()
sf.randomfunction(test=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

There in no variable named `good` or `wrong` in your main module. However you passed them to this function:

```
selected_function.randomfunction(good, wrong)
```